# Xamarin Forms - Update UI element from itself doesn't work

Tags: user-interface, xamarin.forms, updates

I'm currently working on Map UI update.

I have a `public List<string> PolylineAddressPoints` which has a `setter` where a method is called. The method, which is called, updates `public List<GeoPosition> PolylineCoordinates`.

When the `public List<GeoPosition> PolylineCoordinates` has been update, then the renderer is updating the UI of my map.

However, it only works if I edit the list from the `MainPage.xaml.cs`.

I search during a long moment on the web why my map want not update by itself without find any solution. Does the elements needs to be updated from the UI thread?

My main goal is just to update it directly from the list..

My customMap:

```
public class CustomMap : Map
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty PolylineAddressPointsProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PolylineAddressPoints), typeof(List<string>), typeof(CustomMap), new List<string>(), BindingMode.TwoWay);
    public List<string> PolylineAddressPoints
    {
        get { return (List<string>)GetValue(PolylineAddressPointsProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PolylineAddressPointsProperty, value);
            generatePolylineCoordinates(value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty PolylineCoordinatesProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PolylineCoordinates), typeof(List<GeoPosition>), typeof(CustomMap), new List<GeoPosition>(), BindingMode.TwoWay);
    public List<GeoPosition> PolylineCoordinates
    {
        get { return (List<GeoPosition>)GetValue(PolylineCoordinatesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PolylineCoordinatesProperty, value); }
    }

    private async void generatePolylineCoordinates(List<string> value)
    {
        this.PolylineCoordinates = await GeneratePolylineCoordinates(value);
        MessagingCenter.Send<App>((App)Application.Current, "PolylineUpdated");
    }
}
```

I tried using the `MessagingCenter` but it doesn't works.. It look like the thread is cancel, I said that because I don't see the debug as well.. I don't understand what is happening..

There is the MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MapPolylinePage : ContentPage
{
    public List<string> AddressPointList { get; set; }

    public MapPolylinePage()
    {
        base.BindingContext = this;

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App>((App)Application.Current, "PolylineUpdated", (sender) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("--DEBUG ADDRESS--");
            foreach (string item in MapTest.PolylineAddressPoints)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Adress => [{0}]", item);
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("--DEBUG ADDRESS--");

            Debug.WriteLine("--DEBUG POSITION--");
            foreach (GeoPosition item in MapTest.PolylineCoordinates)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("GeoPosition => [{0}/{1}]", item.Latitude, item.Longitude);
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("--DEBUG POSITION--");
        });

        AddressPointList = new List<string>()
        {
            "Le Mans, 72100, France",
            "Arnages, 72230, France",
            "Allonnes, 72700, France"
        };

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and the MainPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <local:CustomMap x:Name="MapTest" PolylineAutoUpdate="True" PolylineAddressPoints="{Binding AddressPointList}" PolylineColor="Aqua" PolylineWidth="5"
                 VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Thank in advance !

Comment: `BindableProperty.Create` has an overload for OnPropertyChanged. I would move your method call to there instead of messing with the setter. Are you experiencing an exception in `GeneratePolylineCoordinates`? The `async void` part also scares me. Try enabling your debugger to break on all System.Exceptions and see if there is an exception happening.

Comment: Thank for your answer ! `private async void generatePolylineCoordinates(List<string> value)` has been created in order to be able to use the `await` operator to call `GeneratePolylineCoordinates(value);`